# Get part of string that is not html in Java

Tags: java, html, string, parsing, substring

In my Java application I have String that have to be edited. The problem is that these Strings can contain HTML tags/elements, which should not be edited (no id to retrieve element).

Scenario (add -):

```
String a = "<span> <table> </table>  </span> <div></div> <div> text 2</div>";
should become: <span> <table> </table>  </span> <div></div> <div> -text 2</div>  

String b = "text";
should become: -text

String c = "<p> t </p>";
should become: <p> -t </p>
```

My question is: How can I retrieve the text in a string that can contain html tags (cannot add id or class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an XML parsing library.

```
String newText = null;
for ( Node node : document.nodes() ) {
  if ( node.text() != null ) newText = "-" + node.text();
}
```

*note that this is pseudo.*

`newText` will now be `-text` or whatever the node text is.

**EDIT:**
Your question is a bit ambiguous in terms of "the text **can** contain html elements."
If it doesn't contain html tags, then you cannot use an XML parser, which brings up the question.. if it **doesn't** contain tags, then why can't you just do...

```
String newString = "-" + a;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason is that I do not know beforehand if the string will contain html or not